# How do I add wp_edit (rich text) to this custom post?

Tags: wordpress, richtext

I am working on a free template called Tesla. It has a nice portfolio custom post, but it doesn't allow you to edit the text in rich form. My client is looking for a rich text editor and the template suits its needs, but he doesn't want to manually add the breaks, bolds, etc.

It is in the teslawp_porftolio where the text is declared, how do I turn on the wp_edit? Or, is there any other way to add rich text?

```
<?php

return array(

'teslawp_main' => array(
    'name' => 'Main Slider',
    'term' => 'slide',
    'term_plural' => 'slides',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'options' => array(
        'description' => array(
            'type' => 'text', 
            'description' => 'Enter description of the slide',
            'title' => 'Description',
        ),
        'image' => array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'description' => 'Image of the slide',
            'title' => 'Image',
            'default' => 'holder.js/960x407/auto'
        ),
        'url' => array(
            'type' => 'line',
            'description' => '(Optional) URL applied to the title',
            'title' => 'URL',
            'default' => ''
        )
    ),
    'output_default' => 'main',
    'output' => array(
        'main' => array(
            'shortcode' => 'tesla_main_slider',
            'view' => 'views/main_slider_view',
            'shortcode_defaults' => array(
                'style' => '',
                'speed' => 4,
                'pause' => 8,
                'toggle_caption' => true
            )
        )
    ),
    'icon' => '../images/favicon.png'
),
'teslawp_clients' => array(
    'name' => 'Clients Slider',
    'term' => 'slide',
    'term_plural' => 'slides',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'options' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'description' => 'Image of the slide',
            'title' => 'Image',
            'default' => 'holder.js/144x65/auto'
        ),
        'url' => array(
            'type' => 'line',
            'description' => '(Optional) URL for the image',
            'title' => 'URL',
            'default' => ''
        )
    ),
    'output_default' => 'main',
    'output' => array(
        'main' => array(
            'shortcode' => 'tesla_clients_slider',
            'view' => 'views/clients_slider_view',
            'shortcode_defaults' => array(
                'title' => __('our clients','teslawp'),
                'style' => 'style'
            )
        )
    ),
    'icon' => '../images/favicon.png'
),
'teslawp_secondary' => array(
    'name' => 'Secondary Slider',
    'term' => 'slide',
    'term_plural' => 'slides',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'options' => array(
        'image' => array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'description' => 'Image of the slide',
            'title' => 'Image',
            'default' => 'holder.js/682x330/auto'
        )
    ),
    'output_default' => 'main',
    'output' => array(
        'main' => array(
            'shortcode' => 'tesla_secondary_slider',
            'view' => 'views/secondary_slider_view',
            'shortcode_defaults' => array(
                'style' => '',
                'speed' => 4,
                'pause' => 8
            )
        )
    ),
    'icon' => '../images/favicon.png'
),

'teslawp_portfolio' => array(
    'name' => 'Portfolio',
    'term' => 'portfolio item',
    'term_plural' => 'portfolio items',
    'has_single' => true,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'options' => array(
        'small_description' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'description' => 'Breve descripción (mostrada en el home)',
            'title' => 'Breve descripción (mostrada en el home)',
        ),

        'full_description' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'description' => 'Objetivo del programa (mostrado en la página del programa). Favor de usar HTML.',
            'title' => 'Objetivo del programa (mostrado en la página del programa). Favor de usar HTML.',
        ),
        'small_image' => array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'description' => 'Imagen de 240x240px que se mostrará en el home.',
            'title' => 'Imagen de 240x240px que se mostrará en el home.',
            'default' => 'holder.js/240x240/auto'
        ),

        'informacion' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'description' => 'Información completa del programa. Favor de usar HTML.',
            'title' => 'Información completa del programa. Favor de usar HTML.',
        ),

        'image_slider' => array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'description' => 'Slider dentro de la página del programa.',
            'title' => 'Slider dentro de la página del programa.',
            'default' => 'holder.js/627x330/auto',
            'multiple' => true
        ),
        'categories' => array(
            'type' => 'line',
            'description' => 'Fecha en la que se realizará el curso.',
            'title' => 'Fecha en la que se realizará el curso.',
            'default' => ''
        ),
        'skills' => array(
            'type' => 'line',
            'description' => 'Precio del curso.',
            'title' => 'Precio del curso.',
            'default' => ''

        )
    ),
    'output_default' => 'main',
    'output' => array(
        'main' => array(
            'shortcode' => 'tesla_portfolio',
            'view' => 'views/portfolio_view',
            'shortcode_defaults' => array(
                'no_more' => false
            )
        ),
        'single' => array(
            'view' => 'views/portfolio_single_view',
            'shortcode_defaults' => array(
                'style' => '',
                'speed' => 4,
                'pause' => 8
            )
        )
    ),
    'icon' => '../images/favicon.png'
),
'teslawp_testimonial' => array(
    'name' => 'Testimonials',
    'term' => 'testimonial',
    'term_plural' => 'testimonials',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'options' => array(
        'testimonial' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'description' => 'Enter text of the testimonial',
            'title' => 'Testimonial',
        ),
        'image' => array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'description' => 'Author\'s image',
            'title' => 'Author\' Image',
            'default' => 'holder.js/126x126/auto'
        ),
        'author' => array(
            'type' => 'line',
            'description' => 'Author of the testimonial (Ex. John Doe)',
            'title' => 'Author\'s Name',
            'default' => ''
        ),
        'url' => array(
            'type' => 'line',
            'description' => '(Optional) url to the author\'s page',
            'title' => 'Author\'s Url',
            'default' => ''
        )
    ),
    'output_default' => 'main',
    'output' => array(
        'main' => array(
            'shortcode' => 'tesla_testimonial',
            'view' => 'views/testimonial_view',
            'shortcode_defaults' => array(
                'wide' => true,
                'class' => '',
                'speed' => 4,
                'pause' => 8
            )
        )
    ),
    'icon' => '../images/favicon.png'
)
```

);

Answer (score 0):

So, to a post type show the rich editor, you need only to add the post content field ('editor') property in the post type.

If the content field is showing, but not the editor, maybe you switched to the source code editor. It can be switched here: 
[image: toggle HTML and CODE]

But, if the post type shows no text area, then you need to modify the post type. In this case it would be:

```
add_post_type_support( 'post_type_name', array('editor') )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks SidGBF, however, I don't know where to add that piece of code in the bigger code I added. Could you be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Of course! This piece of code is added in any place at the functions.php of the theme. If you allow me to suggest, create a child theme (http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and in the functions.php of this theme you only add that line. Using a child theme will protect you when updating.